# How to update the role of the user by deleting its role and inserting a new role?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following database structure:

**User table:** Name, Username, Department (Username is the primary key)

**Roles table:** RoleID, RoleName (RoleID is the primary key)

**UserRole table:** UserRoleID, Username, RoleID (UserRoleID is the primary key)

I want to update the role of the user by deleting its current role and inserting a new role instead of using UPDATE command, but I don't know how to do that.

My ASP.NET Code:

```
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        Current Role:
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000099" />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server" TextAlign="left">
                            <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="Admin" />
                            <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="Contribute" />
                            <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="User" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
                        <span id="infoSpan" runat="server" style="color:Red;"></span>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

And the C# code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If one of the items is selected AND a username exists in the Username session object update the user role
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psTest;Integrated Security=True";
            string cmdText = "UPDATE Roles SET RoleName = '" + radio1.SelectedValue + "'" +
                "WHERE Username = '" + Session["Username"].ToString() + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I am not using ASP.NET Membership. And I came up with database design to make the database fully normalized. Also, because the company may ask me to give the user mare than one role at the same time.

Comment: i guess you should do UPDATE not delete and insert.

Comment: Give some more details... are you using aspnet membership?

Comment: i didnt understand that you have mentioned in UserRole table: UserRoleID and RoleID what's the difference between them...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for not wanting to use the update, which seems better in my opinion, by here's what you would do for what you want.

```
protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //If one of the items is selected AND a username exists in the Username session object update the user role
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && Session["Username"] != null)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
            string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM UserRole where Username=@Username";
            string cmdText = "INSERT INTO UserRole (RoleID,Username) values(@RoleID,@Username)";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //first the delete command
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteCommand, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",Session["Username"].ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //Now the insert
                    cmd.CommandText=cmdText;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear(); //need this because still has params from del comm
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID",radio1.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",Session["Username"].ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Notice how the SQLCommands use parameters. This is to avoid SQL Injection attacks. Your code as you have it can be easily attacked. All one needs to do is do something similar with the username value to what [happens on this comic](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Also note that my code did not enclose the execution of both sql statements in one transaction. This is left to you as an exercise. You need to do it in case an exception occurs while executing the second -insert- statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I tried to execute it I got an error with the last 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: It gave me the yellow page with giving this error: (Invalid column name 'RoleName'.) with coloring the last (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();) with a red color

Comment: @user976711: well, the error is pretty obvious and you should be able to fix it easily: it clearly says that column `RoleName` is invalid and clearly **it is** invalid. It should have been `RoleID` (look at  the schema you posted). I will update my answer, but seriously dude, this is so easy to detect and fix that you should have done it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> First off I would recommend the ASP.NET membership model if you aren't
>   using it already. It contains all the commands to remove and add roles
>   from users.
>
> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx][1]
>
> If you really want to delete then insert you would need these
>   commands:
>
> ```
>  DELETE FROM UserRole where UserRoleID='theId'
>  INSERT INTO UserRole VALUES (Username, RoleID)
> ```
>
> or you can do the delete by roleId and username if needed
>
> UPDATE: You mentioned that you didnt use the ASP.NET membership model
>   because you wanted the database fully normalized and maybe add more
>   than 2 roles to a user.
>
> The ASP.NET membership model is fully normalized and can assign
>   multiple roles per user.
>
> [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx